# Best Azure service for app with custom HttpListener

Tags: c#, azure, httplistener

I have own relative complex app which implement own http server via HttpListener. Currently I looking for best way to deploy to Azure. But I ‘am new in Azure, so I don’t know which service is best for my app.

What I need:

- Continued running (long start time)
- Support for minimal Http interface via HttpListener (I really doesn’t need MVC WebApi)
- I will be happy if it will be easy deployment (automatization with VSO)
- Also i don't need to much mantain pure VM :)

From my research I think best will be WebJob but on some [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) I read it's for "RSS aggregation, File maintenance, such as aggregating or cleaning up log files etc.." And it's not look like best solution for relative complex app.

Comment: This question is too broad (and opinion-soliciting). Lots of ways to solve this: Web Apps, cloud services (web roles or worker roles), VM's (even though you stated you don't think you need them), mobile services, API service... We don't have any further details of your app. Web Apps have limitations, as do Cloud Services. There are lots of tradeoffs. No right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy this as a standard web app. Web apps support the full .net 4.6 stack so will run HTTPListener quite happily.

You can enable Always On to ensure that your site is kept active. You can do this from Application Settings within the Portal. (it can also be scripted)

> Indicates that your web app needs to be loaded at all times. By default, web apps are unloaded after they have been idle. It is recommended that you enable this option when you have continuous web jobs running on the web app.

There is a good, though old now! [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance) by  Scott Guthrie at Microsoft that might be useful.

Comment: This isn't a "best way" - it's "a" way. Web apps have their pros and cons (such as limited ports that may be listened to). We have zero information about any other app needs. Plus, there are cloud services (web roles, worker roles), VMs (even though the OP doesn't think he needs it), mobile service, API service...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, it wasn't intended to be a 'best way' it was intended to be a way. If the OP, or the next boat from google, reads this and realises it doesn't work because it needs access to x app, or y port, or z doohickey then it has helped someone to get closer to an answer. Someone who knows Azure knows the information they need to give, someone who doesn't just says they need *this* feature. At that point we can either suggest a 'way' that will yield more information, or we can tell them to go away because their question is too broad. My preference is the former.

Comment: @Michael But I must create empty asp.net Web Application or not? I’m not sure if is best referenced whole ASP.NET.

Comment: @DavidMakogon- You have true. I did not write to much detail. But application is own Graph implementation for search routes on it. And also update data to DB (detect which is new and which is just update). This function is wrap to simple api. Currently I run it on my local machine as simple console app and its work fine.